# How to animate burgermenu - cross

Tags: css, animation

i have started to animate with CSS3.

I tried to create an animated burgermenu but the result is a little bit ugly. 
The top and bottom bars translate a little bit to the right. So the rotate animation is not really smooth and right.

Here is the result 
[image]  => [image]

This is my code:

/* HTML */

```
<div id="burger">
  <span id="burgerTop" class="burgerLineTop"></span>
  <span id="burgerCenter" class="burgerLineCenter"></span>
  <span id="burgerBottom" class="burgerLineBottom"></span>
</div>
```

/* CSS CODE */

```
#burger {
  position: absolute;  
  margin: 50px;
}

.burgerLineTop {
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
}

.burgerLineCenter {
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
}

.burgerLineBottom {
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
}

.burgerLineTopAnimation {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.burgerLineCenterAnimation {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.burgerLineBottomAnimation {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

/* JS */

```
var burgermenu = document.querySelector('#burger');

burgermenu.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var burgerTop = document.querySelector('#burgerTop');
    var burgerCenter = document.querySelector('#burgerCenter');
    var burgerBottom = document.querySelector('#burgerBottom');
    var burgerTopCL = burgerTop.classList;
    var burgerCenterCL = burgerCenter.classList;
    var burgerBottomCL = burgerBottom.classList;

    burgerTopCL.contains('burgerLineTopAnimation') ? burgerTopCL.remove('burgerLineTopAnimation') : burgerTopCL.add('burgerLineTopAnimation');
    burgerCenterCL.contains('burgerLineCenterAnimation') ? burgerCenterCL.remove('burgerLineCenterAnimation') : burgerCenterCL.add('burgerLineCenterAnimation');
    burgerBottomCL.contains('burgerLineBottomAnimation') ? burgerBottomCL.remove('burgerLineBottomAnimation') : burgerBottomCL.add('burgerLineBottomAnimation');
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TorbenG/pksbnjg5/)

Maybe i made something wrong with the transition-origin...

I know that there are a lot of code examples at jsfiddle etc. But i want to learn css animations etc correctly. So i want to understand why my code is not good and what i should be better. And how css animations / css really works.

I hope you could help me :)
thanks and have a good friday.

Answer (score 2):

Position the bars so they're in the same position relative to the parent in both states, then use `transform-origin: 50%`

```js
var burgermenu = document.querySelector('#burger');

burgermenu.addEventListener('click', function() {
 var burgerTop = document.querySelector('#burgerTop');
 var burgerCenter = document.querySelector('#burgerCenter');
 var burgerBottom = document.querySelector('#burgerBottom');
 var burgerTopCL = burgerTop.classList;
 var burgerCenterCL = burgerCenter.classList;
 var burgerBottomCL = burgerBottom.classList;

 burgerTopCL.contains('burgerLineTopAnimation') ? burgerTopCL.remove('burgerLineTopAnimation') : burgerTopCL.add('burgerLineTopAnimation');
 burgerCenterCL.contains('burgerLineCenterAnimation') ? burgerCenterCL.remove('burgerLineCenterAnimation') : burgerCenterCL.add('burgerLineCenterAnimation');
 burgerBottomCL.contains('burgerLineBottomAnimation') ? burgerBottomCL.remove('burgerLineBottomAnimation') : burgerBottomCL.add('burgerLineBottomAnimation');
});
```

```css
#burger {
  position: absolute;  
  margin: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed #999;
  width: 50px;
}

.burgerLineTop {
  top: 7.5px;
}

.burgerLineCenter {
    top: 22.5px;
}

.burgerLineBottom {
    top: 37.5px;
}

#burger span {
  height: 5px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.burgerLineTopAnimation {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.burgerLineCenterAnimation {
  opacity: 0;
}

.burgerLineBottomAnimation {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.burgerLineBottomAnimation, .burgerLineTopAnimation {
    transform-origin: center;
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="burger">
  <span id="burgerTop" class="burgerLineTop"></span>
  <span id="burgerCenter" class="burgerLineCenter"></span>
  <span id="burgerBottom" class="burgerLineBottom"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but the burgermenu will move to the top, because of the top 50%...

Comment: @TorbenG k, I'm tinkering with it to get them to stay in the same spot...

Comment: @TorbenG updated the positioning so that everything is centered in both states. That better? Also consolidated your css a bit.